# Virtualbox access a port on host's localhost from guest as localhost (guest->host port forward)

Tags: port, virtualbox, nat, portforwarding

The situation is that I try to test a webpage in IE8 (Win 7 guest OS), and for some reason I have many "`http://localhost:8000`" url used in development environment used in js ajax, so I cannot access my host's server through the ip.
So what I want to do is that when I say `http://localhost:8000` in guest's browser, it should forward the request to host's local port 8000.
Any idea?

Comment: Of course there is a way (especially in Win7), that you write `10.0.2.2    localhost` to your hosts file (the ip of the gateway is the ip of the host machine)

Answer (score 2):

You should edit `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.
Set **localhost** to point to the IP address of your host machine.

For example:

```
192.168.0.10    localhost
```

Cheers!